# aws vpc s3 endpoint cli syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I have an s3 vpc endpoint created, but I cannot work out what the api cli syntax on an ec2 instance to interact with the bucket is.

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName"`

from the VPC config page

`ENDPOINTID=vpce-dxxxxxxx` `SERVICE=com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3`

s3 policy

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",    "Id": "MyPolicy",   "Statement": [      {           "Sid": "MySidId",           "Effect": "Allow",          "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/MyRole"          },          "Action": "s3:*",           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName"         }   ] }
```

ec2 role policy

```
{
             "Sid": "MySidId",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [
                 "s3:ListBucket",
                 "s3:GetObject",
                 "s3:PutObject",
                 "s3:DeleteObject"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                 "*"
             ]
         }
```

describe-prefix-lists

```
{
             "VpcEndpoints": [
                 {
                     "PolicyDocument": "{\"Version\":\"2008-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}",
                     "VpcId": "vpc-ec96cxxxx",
                     "State": "available",
                     "ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3",
                     "RouteTableIds": [
                         "rtb-87cexxxx",
                         "rtb-bbcexxxx"
                     ],
                     "VpcEndpointId": "vpce-d983xxxx",
                     "CreationTimestamp": "2016-01-05T13:28:41Z"
                 }
             ]
         }
```

route table `rtb-bbcexxxx` has correct `"PrefixListId": "pl-6da54xxx"`

I have tried the following

```
    aws s3 --profile prf1 --region eu-west-1 ls MyBucketName.com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3
    aws s3 --profile prf1 --region eu-west-1 ls com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3.MyBucketName
    aws s3 --profile prf1 --region eu-west-1 ls com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3/MyBucketName
```

combinations but get

```
A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

What is the correct syntax to address this endpoint? is it just s3://MyBucketName??

thx

Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be, yes -- nothing about the way you actually access the bucket should change.

Associating the endpoint prefix list with a subnet essentially hijacks the routes to the public IP addresses returned by DNS for the S3 region, so that the traffic you send to S3 traverses the "endpoint" rather than being sent through the Internet gateway (igw-xxxxxxxx) -- from your perspective, it's just an IP routing change within the VPC infrastructure, so you should need to do nothing different whether you have provisioned an S3 endpoint or not.

Of course, I suspect there is actually more to it than "just" a route table change, but whatever else may be going on behind the scenes, the rest of it consists of implementation details that are internal to AWS and not relevant to how the service appears to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
aws s3 ls  --region eu-west-1 s3://MyBucketName
```

this should work fine with endpoints. S3Uris are prefixed with `s3://`